# Android studio 3.0 profiling find my activities and fragments size

Tags: android, profiling, android-studio-3.0

I read [articles](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler.html) about profiling and tried it in Android studio 3.0.

But I'm still curious about next:
**1)** how can I find, which activities and fragments are storing in memory now?
**2)** which memory size are they consuming at the moment?
**3)** maybe more detailed memory consumption (by objects)?

I only started an investigation about profiling and app performance, please help with it or show good articles (with examples in the latest Android studio version).

As a first question my app now consumes 90Mb of memory. When I dump java heap, I see next (btw, are those numbers in bits?):

[image]

But I really cannot understand, which of that numbers relates to my objects/activities etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yea even I would like to know an answer for this. Upvoted the question and commented to follow any updates in the thread.